# Month start from user define

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eg3Df.png)

The requirements says that each month starts from the 22nd and end on next month 21st.

our company Month start from 22nd each month and last day of month is 21st so i need to calculation regard compnay months

```
for example 
date                              output
22nd Oct 2017 to 21st Nov 2017 =  Nov 2017
22nd Nov 2017 to 21st Dec 2017 =  Dec 2017
22nd Dec 2017 to 21st Jan 2018 =  Jan 2018
22nd Jan 2018 to 21st Feb 2018 =  Feb 2018
```

so when i run the query so it will look on dates and give me month name with year

Comment: how can  `21 Nov 2017` be `NOV 2017` AND in the next line `DEC 2017` ??

Comment: out company Month start from 22nd each month and last day of month is 21th so i need to calculation regard compnay mopnths

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed my answer as per your comments.

Try the code yourself here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4b3e5/5

```
declare @MyTable table (MyDate datetime)

insert into @MyTable (MyDate) 
values ('20171022'), ('20171121'), ('20171122'), ('20171221'), ('20171222'), ('20180121'), ('20180221')

select t.MyDate,
       case when datepart(day, t.MyDate) > 21 then datename(month, dateadd(month, 1, t.MyDate)) + ' ' + datename(year, dateadd(month, 1, t.MyDate))
            else datename(month, t.MyDate) + ' ' + datename(year, t.MyDate)
       end
from   @MyTable t
```

the result now is

```
MyDate      | COLUMN1   
------------|--------------
22/10/2017  | November 2017 
21/11/2017  | November 2017 
22/11/2017  | December 2017 
21/12/2017  | December 2017 
22/12/2017  | January 2018  
21/01/2018  | January 2018  
21/02/2018  | February 2018
```

If you only need the first 3 chars from month, use the substring to get them like this

```
select t.MyDate,
       case when datepart(day, t.MyDate) > 21 then substring(datename(month, dateadd(month, 1, t.MyDate)), 1, 3) + ' ' + datename(year, dateadd(month, 1, t.MyDate))
            else substring(datename(month, t.MyDate), 1, 3) + ' ' + datename(year, t.MyDate)
       end
from   @MyTable t
```

Now the result is

```
MyDate      | COLUMN1   
------------|--------------
22/10/2017  | Nov 2017  
21/11/2017  | Nov 2017  
22/11/2017  | Dec 2017  
21/12/2017  | Dec 2017  
22/12/2017  | Jan 2018  
21/01/2018  | Jan 2018  
21/02/2018  | Feb 2018
```

Comment: yea thts great but what i m looking is when date  > 21/10/2017 and < 21/11/2017 these will count as november 2017

Comment: So `21/10/2017` does not counts as november ? That is not like the example in your question. Please edit your question and describe the exact rules for this

Comment: our company Month start from 22nd each month and last day of month is 21st so i need to calculation regard compnay months

Comment: Please edit your question and describe the exact rules for this

Comment: I altered my answer, hope this is what you want then

Comment: its working fine but when 22nd Dec 2017 to 21st Jan 2018so output coming dec 2018

Comment: also 21/01/2018 will come out as JAN 2018

Comment: Check the 1st post i upload the Image

Comment: 21/12/2017  | Dec 2018   in your outpur see its showing dec 2018 its should show 2017

Comment: 06/12/2017 is not > 21 so it should say december, that are your own rules. As I said earlier, desribe your rules better so we can help you with it

Comment: 21/12 should read december, that is how it shows up in your example

Comment: in my example 22nd Nov till 21st dec = dec 2017 not dec 2018

Comment: Yes you are right, I made a small mistake. I have corrected my answer again

Comment: Thanks 
i used this one 
case when datepart(day, saledate) > 21 then datename(month, dateadd(month, 1, saledate))
 + ' ' + datename(year, dateadd(month, 1, saledate))
            else datename(month, saledate) + ' ' + datename(year, dateadd(month, 0, saledate))
       end

Comment: in the ELSE there should not be an DATAADD, that is what I changed in my answer yesterday. Is it working now as you expect ?

Comment: OK, please consider to upvote and/or mark the answer as solution then. Thanks